# Selenium WebDriver + Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup, selenium-webdriver

Нужно вытащить расписание вот с этой страницы: *http://ruz.spbstu.ru/faculty/98/groups*.

В верхней части 6 кнопок, которые выполняют JS скрипт. И при нажатии которых, меняется расписание.

Что я сделал:

- с помощью JSOUP вытащил расписание при нажатых кнопках "очная" + "бакалавр". Это просто т.к. они включены по дефолту.
- потом с помощью Selenium нажал на кнопку "бакалавр". Да загрузился нужный фрейм с другим расписанием. Но адрес траницы тот же. И бесполезно его передавать в JSOUP для парсинга. Т.к. при загрузке в JSOUP я получу ту же страницу с дефолтно нажатыми кнопками, что и первый раз.

Вопрос:

- как передать код страницы с нужным фреймом после нажатия на кнопки в JSOUP.
- а если это невозможно, мне придется парсить дальше с помощью Selenium?

Comment: JSoup в вашей ситуации вообще не нужен, имхо. В селениуме вы можете точно так же выбирать элементы. Селениум даже лучше, ибо он и xpath умеет, и css селекторы понимает, и JS вполняет.

Comment: Я с ним знаком буквально час. Спасибо. Буду разбираться.

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем разобрался сам.
Передать код страницы проще простого , метод - *getPageSource()*.

Как оказалось для парсинга страниц селениум не очень удобен. JSOUP в разы проще, да и быстрее. Так что, на мой взгляд, лучше использовать Selenium только для нажития кнопок, заполнение форм и прочее.